# How to access the java constructor?

Tags: java, class

A class WeightedQuick union is defined but there is public QuickunionFind(int N) what is it ?Is it a method then how do i pass it the value N, or if it something else how shoulf the value of N be passed to it or how can it be acessed 
Thank you for everyone who answered, I am new to coding, realized the question was silly.

```
public class WeightedQuickUnionUF {
private int[] id;    // id[i] = parent of i
private int[] sz;    // sz[i] = number of objects in subtree rooted at i
private int count;   // number of components

/**
 * Initializes an empty union-find data structure with N isolated components 0 through N-1.
 * @throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException if N < 0
 * @param N the number of objects
 */
public WeightedQuickUnionUF(int N) {
    count = N;
    id = new int[N];
    sz = new int[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        id[i] = i;
        sz[i] = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the inner class in your shown code?

Comment: That's constructor. Not inner class

Comment: Where we can see `QuickunionFind`

Comment: I *highly* recommend a beginner's book on Java, or starting with the tutorials provided by Oracle.

Comment: the question is incomprehensible. is impossible to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no inner classes here.

You have defined a class called `WeightedQuickUnionUF`.  Classes are created by doing this

```
int n = 42;
WeightedQuickUnionUF myInstanceOfThisClass = new WeightedQuickUnionUF(n);
```

In order to define what the class creation code looks like (the part after the kewword `new`), a class has a method called a constructor which has the same name as the class itself, in your case

```
public WeightedQuickUnionUF(int N)
```

This says that an instance of the class `WeightedQuickUnionUF` can be created and given a value which will be called `N` inside that method.

In order to use this, your program needs an entry point (the place it runs from) like so

```
 public static void main(String args)
 { 
    int n = 42;
    WeightedQuickUnionUF myInstanceOfThisClass = new WeightedQuickUnionUF(n);
 }
```

You now have a variable which contains an instance of your class called `myInstanceOfThisClass`, you will then be able to run your class from a console window or IDE or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

There is no inner class in your code.

Since it is a method that doesn't have a return value, you can tell that it is a [*constructor*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html), that is used to initialize your class. You pass in the value when you create a new instance of `WeightedQuickUnionUF`, for example like this:

```
WeightedQuickUnionUF weightedQuickUnionUF = new WeightedQuickUnionUF(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the constructor of the class. You can call it with something like:
`new WeightedQuickUnionUF(1);`

Answer (score 0):

What you mean is `public WeightedQuickUnionUF(int N)`, right? This is the constructor of your class. It is called whenever you create a new instance of this class, e.g. `new WeightedQuickUnionUF(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

I take it you're new to java programming? A "method" with the same name as the class in which it is defined and no return type is called a constructor. It is executed whenever an object of that class is instantiated.

If you were unaware of this, then I'd suggest you try a few java tutorials.